# How to check if for example 30 min have passed?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

i have the following Code:

```
if (v != null && DateTime.Now > v.Besetzt_Von)
{

    Debug.WriteLine("Hallo, das ist die Ausgabe! : " + v.Thema + v.Besetzt_Von + v.Besetzt_Bis);
    string clientId = GetClientId(req);

    DateTime TimeCheck = v.Besetzt_Von;

    if (TimeCheck.AddMinutes(30) > v.Besetzt_Von)
    {
        String hql = "UPDATE Buchung as b " +
        "set STORNO = :Storno " +
        "where ID IN (SELECT rr.Buchung FROM Raumreservierung rr " +
        "where BESETZT_VON = :Von and Raum IN (SELECT r.ID FROM Raum r " +
        "join r.Panel pl where pl.ID = :PanelId))";


        IQuery query = CurrentSession.CreateQuery(hql);
        query.SetParameter("Storno", DateTime.Now);
        query.SetParameter("Von", v.Besetzt_Von);
        query.SetParameter("PanelId", clientId);
        int result = query.ExecuteUpdate();
        Debug.WriteLine("Rows affected: " + result);
    }
}
```

I want that if for example Besetzt_Von = 14:00 o'clock, the Query only gets executed if 30 minutes have passed (14:30). I did that with the if clause, but it does not work. The Query is always executing. What iam doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you think this `TimeCheck.AddMinutes(30) > v.Besetzt_Von` would always be true ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change

```
if (TimeCheck.AddMinutes(30) > v.Besetzt_Von)
```

which doesn't do anything (this means if v.Besetz_von < v.BesetzVon + 30 minutes, which is of course always true)

to

```
if (DateTime.Now > v.Besezt_Von.AddMinutes(30))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// DateTime TimeCheck = v.Besetzt_Von; <-- you don't need this

if (DateTime.Now > v.Besetzt_Von.AddMinutes(30))
{
    // ...
}
```